# How to draft a recommendation letter for myself to be approved by the department head?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I have worked in the IT department with my current employer for a few years. I am planning to leave this job soon. My department head has agreed to sign a recommendation letter for me.

However, he is not my direct manager. He is the department head, while I am leading a working level support team. He is like my manager's, manager's, manager. He's a nice person and has agreed to do this as a good gesture.

He asked me to draft the letter and let him review. But I have no idea where to start.  Should I describe my job from his angle?  Should I just give a short summary because he doesn't know my duties well as he doesn't managed me directly.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the recommendation letter is meant for you, to be written/signed by the department head, but they have asked you to draft a copy?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes.  The letter is for me. My department head will review,  amend and sign on it.  I will use this letter for my future job interview.

Comment: Is this a recommendation for school or for another professional position?

Comment: @Jay it is for my future job hunting not for schooling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the letter depend on a lot of factors. What purpose are you going to use this letter for. Is it going to be for a job? or an academic endeavour? Maybe you are looking to make use of the good gesture of the department head to get a signed letter which you could use in future?

If you have a clear-cut purpose in your mind, put it in the question, and the content of the letter can be varied.

However, if you are trying to get a general purpose letter, you can keep the body short and simple. Make sure to include the nature of your work and day-to-day duty while on the job.

*To whomsoever it may concern,*

*I have known Mark as an employee who lead the  team in  companies IT department. I found him to be diligent with his duties and always showing enthusiasm in his professional life. He has an innate desire to learn and grow as a professional.*

*I would certainly welcome any opportunity in the future if he wish to work with the organization again.*

*I have no doubt that he'll be will be a valuable addition to any team that he works with in future.*

*I wish his good luck and success in his future endeavours.*

The above is just a starting point for a generic recommendation letter. Do not try to use template/copy-pasted content. Originally and simplicity trumps down adornments any given day. Advise you to keep it short and simple, such that it gets read in a short glance.

Answer (score 5):

**A great recommendation letter is brief (1 page) and includes at least:**

**1. A description of the relationship between recommender and the recommended individual.** How long have you known each other? How closely did you work?

**2. A general affirmation that the recommended individual is a good fit for the program/role.** The letter should identify specific skills or experiences needed by the program/role being applied to and affirm that the individual possesses them.

**3. A specific anecdote or a detailed discussion of an exceptional attribute of the recommended individual.** Stories are memorable - what was a specific time that the recommended individual really demonstrated their strengths?

**4. Thanks to those considering the application.** It’s always a good idea to thank the reader.

You or the recommender could add or re-order as appropriate - no need to stick to a strict structure if it isn’t how the letter would have been written otherwise.

**Avoid using the online templates for recommendation letters.** They are impersonal and obvious.

---

An aside: I imagine you’ll get some protest over the approach you and your colleague are taking to create the letter, but **it’s normal for recommendations to be drafted by the recommended individual and later edited and sent by the recommender.** Just make sure your recommender has plenty of time to edit and submit the letter after you draft it.

Comment: Re #4. Usually these letters are written as if dept head etc wrote them. Thanking the reader for their consideration would seem a bit odd if not coming from the candidate (even if they did write the initial draft), it's like breaking character.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane, I’m suggesting that the recommender thank the recruiter for the opportunity to recommend a colleague and for taking the time to read the letter - apologies that I was ambiguous.